# What is the correct probability distirbution for the given situation?

Tags: probability, distributions, negative-binomial-distribution, truncated-distributions

A game is played until either a player receives their 3rd loss or their 7th win. What is the distribution of the number of wins that the player gets before their 3rd loss?

I was thinking of using a negative binomial X that counts the number of wins before the 3rd loss and then lump the probabilities from 8 wins onwards onto 7 wins resulting in a truncated, inflated distribution. Is this reasonable? I saw a truncated distribution R package that does things differently.

Comment: This problem is over 500 years old: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problem_of_points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it makes sense. Consider $X\sim NB(r=3,p)$, which is the number of wins until the 3rd loss and define the RV $Y$ as $$Y=\begin{cases}X&, X<7\\7&, X\geq 7\end{cases}$$
which will be the number of wins until the 3rd loss or 7-th win. This is true because in all of the situations that leads to $X\geq 7$, we'd have ended up the experiment where we hit the win limit, and all of those cases contribute to the probability $P(Y=7)$, which means $$P(Y=7)=\sum_{i=7}^\infty P(X=i)$$